# How to crawl drupal website by Python Scrapy?

Tags: python, filter, drupal, scrapy

I have a Drupal website(can't show), on it is a html table. I need to crowl rows from this table.

By default view of table is undesirible for crawling:

1. table shows only 15 rows, to see next 15 rows need to click on
   "next" button.
2. there is not column "country", it is in separate
       row.

These two issues resolve by filter:

1. I need to change "15" on "all" rows perpage.
2. Uncheck checkbox and column "country" will apear.

Thereafter table is ready to crowling.

I noticed, when i push on "next" button or change table options in F12 -> Network I see an ajax POST request with big body. There is data which is responsible for "rows per page" and " 'country' column". I tried to make request POST with body that consists from my data. I only get the response "Bad request". Thereafter I saw that in body is data that is responsible for salt. 
I find this salt in html and get it dynamically from html.
At the moment I make POST request, get response 200 , but this page is wrong.

Question:
How i can get page by Scrapy in "ready for crawling" mode? How can i interact with filter from code?

I understand that my explanation of situation is very abstract, but I will be glad to all ideas and solutions! Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: maybe you should use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScrip and Ajax. Selenium can also click elements on page.

Comment: @furas, thank you very much I figured it out
used other filter settings

Comment: Most likely that table is generated by some view, so try to find and edit it. There you can fine tune how many rows you want to display, what fields to display and much more.